# Old textbooks on statistical mechanics

Tags: physics

I am going to teach history of physics next semester. Can anyone name some old textbooks on statistical mechanics? By old, I mean written around 1930 or earlier. I would like to compare the old books and the books nowadays.

Comment: [Josiah Willard Gibbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Willard_Gibbs), [Elementary Principles in Statistical Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_Principles_in_Statistical_Mechanics) (1902). See also [here](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryPrinciplesInStatisticalMechanics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arnold Sommerfeld's last volume of his Lectures on Theoretical Physics, written in the 1940s and published posthumously, downloadable as [pdf file](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.166906)

Max Planck's [Theory of
Heat](https://archive.org/stream/theoryofheatbein007775mbp#page/n7/mode/2up) from 1932

The 1911 article by Paul and Tatiana Ehrenfest in Felix Klein's [Encyklopädie](https://archive.org/stream/p4encyklopdieder04akaduoft#page/n791/mode/2up), of which there is also an English [translation](https://books.google.de/books?id=g0xoBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&dq=ehrenfest+%22encyklop%C3%A4die+article%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVpv3A2qzSAhVIK8AKHVgpAkwQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=ehrenfest%20%22encyklop%C3%A4die%20article%22&f=false)

And here is a host of other books:
https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22Kinetic+theory+of+gases%22&sort=-date